# Catch statement not executing in exception handling of XPath

Tags: java, xpath, try-catch

I have a UI test case in Java which identifies the `userName` text field and enters some value in it. I am trying to implement a try-catch block so that if the try block fails, it executes the catch block. But my code is not executing the catch block at all.

I have tried to use console.log or assert.fail in the catch block to see if it prints the message. But execution does not go to catch block and browser gets closed as soon as try block fails.

```
try {
//retrieves Xpath of userName which is incorrect.
            return browser.setValue(this.getSelector("login_userId_txtbox"), datatablevalue.userName);
        } catch (er) {
            //assert.fail("UserId xpath is incorrect", er);
            return console.log("------>error in XPATH", er);
        }
```

Actual Result: catch block never gets executed.

Expected Result: If xpath does not match, it should print console.log message in catch block.

Comment: "Java" in the question, "Javascript" in the tags - which is it?

Comment: `.setValue` is method in framework? you are passing the the locator and value to that method. And sure what you are doing in that method.

Comment: Yes .setValue sets the value which is passed form locator. And what i want to know -  If value passed is not correct and it should go to catch block and print console message. It's JS based framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an XPath expression selects nothing, it returns an empty node-set. That's not an error, so it doesn't raise an exception. It's a regular result that you need to test for.